# How to MatPlotLib Plot two DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have two DataFrame `north` and `south`. Each has same rows and columns. I would like to plot the speed columns of both DataFrames in one figure as bar chart. I am trying this:

```
ax = south['speed'].plot(kind='bar', color='gray')
north['speed'].plot(kind = 'bar', color='red', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

But it plots only the last dataframe , i.e. only the `north` DataFrame. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you would like to plot just 'speed' column, you have to concatenate dataframes like:

```
df = pd.concat([north, south])
```

or

```
df = north.append(south)
```

2) If you would like to compare 'speed' column of both dataframes, you have to join dataframes along axis=1 like:

```
df = pd.concat([north, south], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

and the call plot method of `df`.

For more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer. But, still have one question. I would like to compare the speed and the index of the `north` and `south` are dateIndex. If the rows are same but the value of index are not then, then what I can do?

Comment: I can not figure out short answer for this problem. May be make group by speed values and then compare data in a group?